# jQuery select dropdown option with only one non-blank option

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

I'm dealing with a storefront package (so I don't have the option to edit core files) and we have dropdown menus to select which front and back the user wants for a business card. Some of the cards have only one option, so the client would like to hide the dropdown menu if there's only one option.

Easy, right?

```
$("select").each(function(){
    var count = $(this).children("option").length;
    if ( count == 1 ) {
        // there's only one option, do something
    }
});
```

That works, but the problem is that the system sometimes generates a blank `<option>` for some of the dropdowns, so there's really two options, but only one "real" option:

```
<select>
    <option></option>
    <option value="Something">A real option</option>
</select>
```

Basically, I need to select `<select>`s that only have one `<option>`, or two `<option>`s and one is just empty.

I can't quite wrap my head around the logic of such an if statement, so if anyone has any suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might be able to just change your selector to `option[value]` or `option:not(:empty)`, depending on if the empty one is always completely empty with no value and no text

Comment: As per the example give, is `<option></option>` always the case? If so, you can remove `<option>` tags with no text within its tags or having no value attribute or value attribute with empty string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `not` method and `:empty` selector:

```
$("select").each(function(){
    var count = $(this).find("option").not(':empty').length;
    if ( count == 1 ) {
        alert('okay')
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TwW9u/)

Comment: Oh hey, that's a way better solution than mine.

Comment: I honestly can't believe I didn't think of that before... so simple. Thanks!

Comment: This way is not working wgen the option value is empy and option text not.

Answer (score 0):

Change the way you're counting them:

```
$('select').each(function() {
    var count = 0;
    $(this).children('option').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).text() ) // true if not empty
        {
            ++count;
        }
    });
    if ( count == 1 ) // count only includes non-empty options
```

That should handle it.